# Google Analytics event on submit

Tags: javascript, forms, google-analytics, dom-events

Simple case, need to send an event to Google right on submitting a form.

I tried like 10 different ways of doing it, but either it doesn't send the GA event, or it doesn't submit the form.

```
<form id="n" action="/" method="post">
```

Does send the event but not the form:

```
<input type="button"
onclick="window._gaq.push(['._trackEvent', 'x', 'x', 'x']);document.getElementById('n').submit();">
```

Tried with a setTimeout - doesn't send the event but submit the form:

```
<input type="button"
onclick="window._gaq.push(['._trackEvent', 'x', 'x', 'x']);window.setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('n').submit();}, 200);">
```

Tried with `type="submit"` on the button, didn't send the event:

```
<input type="submit"
onclick="window._gaq.push(['._trackEvent', 'x', 'x', 'x']);">
```

Tried putting the submit into the GA array, it did submit the button but did not register the event:

```
<input type="submit"
onclick="window._gaq.push(['._trackEvent', 'x', 'x', 'x']);window._gaq.push(function(){document.getElementById('n').submit()});">
```

Tried with jQuery with `onsubmit="doX();"` in the `<form />` but it does not send the event either:

```
<script>
function doX() {
    window._gaq.push(['._trackEvent', 'test', 'test', 'test']);
    document.getElementById('n').submit();
}
</script>
```

Putting `window._gaq.push(['._trackEvent', 'x', 'x', 'x']);` in the console or somewhere in the code works.

Putting `document.getElementById('n').submit();` somewhere in the code or in the console also works.

They don't just work together.

I tried a few more which also didn't make it work.

Comment: Not using the most recent universal GA btw, using the older analytics.

Comment: Your first value should not have a period. It should be just like this `['_trackEvent', 'test', 'test', 'test'])`.

Comment: @colecmc you mean the dot? I have an alias there which I removed to shorten the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery anyway, then just use the submit action.

After your input has loaded, such as at the bottom of the page or inside a window.loaded area:

```
$('input#button').click( function () {
  window._gaq.push(['._trackEvent', 'x', 'x', 'x'])
  this.submit();
});
```

If you switch to the newest version of Google Analytics, they have a Chrome extension that'll show event details in the console, which is pretty nice.

Comment: You do not submit an input, you submit a form. This does not send the event so it doesn't work either :-(